# Inline variables aren't working in TMS Web Core

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment, variable-declaration, inline-variable, tms-web-core

When I try to use an inline variable, then I get a `Syntax error`. Here's my code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSignInClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var UserEmail := edtEmail.Text;
  var UserPassword := edtPassword.Text;
  var UserRememberMe := tglRememberMe.Checked;

  SignIn(UserEmail, UserPassword);
end;
```

The `Syntax error` happens on this line: `var UserEmail := edtEmail.Text;`.

Changing the inline variable to also specify the type doesn't work either:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSignInClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var UserEmail: String := edtEmail.Text;
  var UserPassword: String := edtPassword.Text;
  var UserRememberMe: Boolean := tglRememberMe.Checked;

  SignIn(UserEmail, UserPassword);
end;
```

---

This is valid Delphi code that would work in VCL and FMX, but it doesn't seem to work in TMS Web Core. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [TMS Support Center post](https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/web-core-application-and-inline-variables/12505), the pas2js transpiler (which emits JavaScript code from Object Pascal code) [does not support inline variables](https://wiki.freepascal.org/pas2js#Other_unimplemented_features). So you'll have to use the old-school way of declaring variables:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSignInClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  UserEmail: String;
  UserPassword: String;
  UserRememberMe: Boolean;
begin
  UserEmail := edtEmail.Text;
  UserPassword := edtPassword.Text;
  UserRememberMe := tglRememberMe.Checked;

  SignIn(UserEmail, UserPassword);
end;
```

Comment: As your post becomes older a potential reader might still take it as never changing fact. But telling that it relates to version 2.2.0 (from 2022-02-22) will in 1-2 years a reader to consider checking for a more recent version and if it has been implemented since then. That's why [I put it into your A](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77338024/2) and don't get why you wanted to remove it.